# Phrase for "representative of my day"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase similar to "representative". It may be a single word as well. I've been trying to think of it for days...

Example: A person is having the worst day at work. They get home and try to unwind by having a beer. When they take the beer out of the fridge, they drop it and it explodes making a huge mess. "Well that's just [representative/symbolizes/sums up] my day!"

Comment: Or you could say simply, "Now that tears it!" (pronounced târs).  This expression is akin to the saying, "The straw that broke the camel's back," meaning in this case that the exploding beer was the last straw, or a perfectly awful ending to a perfectly awful day. The verb can mean to separate or pull apart by force, which reminds of the ANE custom of rending (tearing) one's outer garments to indicate deeply felt emotions, such as grief, particularly when an important truth or value is blasphemed or disregarded. Hmmm. Maybe that's where "that tears it" comes from!

Comment: Another fine mess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Well, that just epitomizes my day!" or "That's my day in a nutshell!"

Comment: "that's" in the first example should be "that"; i. e., "Well, that just epitomizes my day!" This question reminds me of American actress Meg Ryan's response to the question, "What is your favorite curse word/phrase?" when she was interviewed on the television program, "In the Actor's Studio" on the cable TV channel, Bravo. That exclamation would precede the answer you are seeking. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppfnsUkf8Dw